# Grails service with multithreading

Tags: multithreading, hibernate, grails, grails-orm, grails-services

Max 10 threads of the below **NewProcessor** will be created at a time if messages are coming in parallel. For testing, 20 messages with the same **param** is used and expected only one record in the DB for **Net** domain but multiple records were created.

After several hours of various changes, I still couldn't figure out the issue...

```
    class NewProcessor implements Runnable {
        ...
        NewService newService = ApplicationContextHolder.getBean("newService")

        public void run(){
            process()
        }

        public boolean process(){
            ...
            def obj = newService.process(param)
            ...
        }
    }

    class NewService {

        NetService netService
        ...

        public Info process(String param){
            Info info = new Info()
            ...

            info.net = netService.getNet(param)
            ...
            ...
            info.save()
        }

        ...
    }

    class NetService {
         public synchronized Info getNet(String param) {

              Rule trule = Rule.findByParam(param)
              Net net = Net.findByRule(trule)
              if (!net){
                    net = new Net(rule: trule).save(flush: true, validate: false)
              }

              return net
         }

         ....
    }
```

Comment: I tried putting Thread.sleep(5000) before _return net_ of _getNet(String param)_ method to see if the session flush is taking time before other thread comes in. It reduced number of created records to 2 record but further increasing the sleep time doesn't help. So there might be some other issues.

Answer (score 1):

I got to make it work by adding **@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)** to getNet() method as below.

```
class NetService {
     @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
     public synchronized Info getNet(String param) {

          Rule trule = Rule.findByParam(param)
          Net net = Net.findByRule(trule)
          if (!net){
                net = new Net(rule: trule).save(flush: true, validate: false)
          }

          return net
     }

     ....
}
```

Comment: I am trying to achieve something very similar, however find by the next request that was block in synchronised, does not return any results and therefore multiple records are created. Which version of Grails and Hibernate did you use?